# Standalone + biblatex breaks bibliography

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, standalone, overleaf-toolkit

### Problem

Bibliography isn't being generated when using the package standalone. Perhaps due to a missing .bbl-file.

### Details

The story is that I tried using the *standalone* package but now my bibliography is broken despite erasing cache and building from scratch.

I'm fairly new to TeX but I've made a minimal project and get consistent results. Running the most recent Overleaf toolkit on my own computer, its TeXLive upgraded to the full scheme.

#### Logs

Looking at the logs I think for some reason a bbl file is not being created:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'output.bbl' not found.
No file output.bbl.

Package biblatex Warning: citation 'nakamoto2008bitcoin'
(biblatex)                was not found at all in the .bbl file,
(biblatex)                bibliography labels cannot be generated,
(biblatex)                please correct the citation.

Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 16.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 16.
(./ch/apter.tex
Chapter 1.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'nakamoto2008bitcoin' on page 1 undefined on input line
 24.

)

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 23.

[1


{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./outp
ut.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                output
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Those are the only warnings I get.

### Minimal project

#### File Structure

```
ch/
    apter.tex
main.tex
references.bib
```

##### File contents:

###### references.bib

```
@article{nakamoto2008bitcoin,
  title={Bitcoin: A peer-to-peer electronic cash system},
  author={Nakamoto, Satoshi},
  journal={Decentralized business review},
  year={2008}
}
```

###### main.tex

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric,
    isbn=true,
    doi=false,
    sorting=none,
    url=true,
    defernumbers=true,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    backend=biber
    ]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}

% Chapters
\import{ch/}{apter.tex}

% Bibliography
\nocite{*} % after conclusion
\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```

###### ch/apter.tex

```tex
\documentclass[class=report, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\ifstandalone
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric,
    isbn=true,
    doi=false,
    sorting=none,
    url=true,
    defernumbers=true,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    backend=biber
    ]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\fi

\begin{document}

\chapter{Method}

We use Blockchain \autocite{nakamoto2008bitcoin}

\end{document}
```

### TL;DR

No bibliography. Minimal project, setup and logs provided.

LOG FILE: https://pastebin.com/ftp49A2b

Comment: The problem is that it tries to find the hile in the current folder, i.e. ch. I remember setting a test to add ../ to the path when standalone was loaded. I don't have my laptop but doable. Note also that I got once really weird bugs with standalone…

Comment: Did you run `biber`? Did it find the `.bib` file? Are you compiling `main` or `ch/apter`? What you've posted isn't a complete log even of the `latex` run. It seems to just be the warnings.

Comment: For the record, I use `standalone` and Biblatex regularly with files all over the place. I tend to keep `.bib` files in the standard location, but I don't have problems when I use one located elsewhere.

Comment: @tobiasBora nothing changed with ../, I still get similar output

Comment: @cfr I edited the post to add a log file (pastebin link)

Comment: @cfr I'm compiling main.tex but the output is similar when compiling the chapter file separately. About running biber, overleaf should handle that on its own...

Comment: Check if a `.blg` file is created. If not, then Biber is not run, which is really bad. If it is present, show its contents.

Comment: According to https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Working_Offline_in_Overleaf you need to use something like `latexmk` if you're working with your local installation of TL in order to get the same functionality. Can you clarify (1) whether you're doing this online or offline and (2) if offline, which command you're using to compile?

Comment: I'm doing it offline, but running github.com/overleaf/overleaf in an officially provided docker container.